# How to RE-ENABLE IPv6 functionality on Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS?

Tags: networking

I enter the following command in a terminal to DISABLE IPv6:

```
for ip_six_devs in all default lo; do sudo sysctl net.ipv6.conf.${ip_six_devs}.disable_ipv6=1; done
```

This works fine. I can go to https://test-ipv6.com/ and it reports 'No IPv6 address detected'
To re-enable it I assumed the following would work:

```
for ip_six_devs in all default lo; do sudo sysctl net.ipv6.conf.${ip_six_devs}.disable_ipv6=0; done
```

but it doesn't, all IPv6 test sites still report 'No IPv6 address detected'
The only way I can re-enable IPv6 is to reboot my machine which isn't practical. What commands should I issue to re-enable it, also is there a command I can use to see its current status ?

Thanks,

Usjes,

Comment: When you disable IPv6 I would expect that any IPv6 addresses you have are dropped by the interfaces. Re-enabling the protocol doesn't magically reapply your network configuration. I would try `sudo systemctl restart networking` after you re-enable the protocol.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

```
sudo systemctl restart networking
```

does indeed achieve the desired effect.
Thanks.

Any suggestions for how to see IPv6 status (enabled/disabled) at any given time ?